# EAP 6.3 basic hibernate update throws Exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss, openshift

I'm using openshift to host a JBoss web application.
However they recently updated to EAP 6.3 which breaks the Hibernate persistence layer.

When a standard update is done using the entity manager I get an exception:

> Every derived table must have its own alias

I understand this error is caused by Hibernate generating invalid MySQL query syntax. 
But how can you circumvent this?

Code:

```
private Object updateObject(Object object) {
    try {
        return em.merge(object);
    } catch(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        log.error("Error updating object");
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Activating SQL queries I find the code performs the following updates:

```
update expence_form 
set create_dat=?, last_update_dat=?, approvedby_id=?, approved_dat=?, comment=?, expence_submitter_id=?, ExternalRef=?, owner_id=?, paidby_id=?, paid_dat=?, season_id=?, status=?, submit_dat=?, submitter_id=?, expenceform_type=?, year=?
where id=?
```

=> OK

```
select count(id) 
from ( 
  select id, create_dat, last_update_dat, expence_amt, expence_date, km_distance, km_expence_amt, route_desc, expence_form_id, comment, event_id, null as description, null as budget_group_id, null as expence_type_id, 1 as clazz_ 
  from fixed_expence_detail
  union 
  select id, create_dat, last_update_dat, expence_amt, expence_date, km_distance, km_expence_amt, route_desc, expence_form_id, null as comment, null as event_id, description, budget_group_id, expence_type_id, 2 as clazz_ 
  from proven_expence_detail
) 
where expence_form_id =?
```

=> NOK as subquery has no alias.

I find the following bug report, but no indication how to resolve the issue.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9139

Currently I'm completely stuck as openshift forces me to use the buggy EAP6.3 version together with MySQL.
How could I circumvent this issue until JBoss fixes it in openshift?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be linked with an inheritance structure using TABLE_PER_CLASS:
For some reason hibernate performs a count query for each table in the inheritance structure on a merge command.

My object structure is like: (The expenceForm object containing a list of ExpenceFormDetails)

ExpenceForm <- ExpenceFormDetails

ExpenceFormDetails (Abstract class)

- FixedExpenceFormDetail
- ProvenExpenceFormDetail

Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="expence_form")
public class ExpenceForm extends BaseEntityIdentityIdImpl
{

//some properties

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="expenceForm", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("expenceDate")
    public List<ExpenceFormDetails> getExpenceFormDetails() {

        return expenceFormDetails;
    }
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class ExpenceFormDetails extends BaseEntitySequenceIdImpl 
         implements Comparable<ExpenceFormDetails>
{

// some properies 

}

@Entity
@Table(name="fixed_expence_detail")
public class FixedExpenceFormDetail extends ExpenceFormDetails
{

//Extra properties

}
```

As i have no clue how to influence the hibernate query i just coded around the issue by writing a manual update command for the object:

```
Query updateQuery = em.createQuery("update ExpenceForm set submitter= :submitter, "
        + "owner= :owner, approvedBy=:approvedBy, paidBy= :paidBy, season= :season, "
        + "expenceSubmitter= :expenceSubmitter, submitDate= :submitDate, approvedDate= :approvedDate, paidDate= :paidDate, externalRef= :externalRef, "
        + "status=:status, type=:type, comment=:comment, year=:year "
        + "where id= :id")
        .setParameter("submitter", f.getSubmitter())
        .setParameter("owner", f.getOwner()).setParameter("approvedBy", f.getApprovedBy()).setParameter("paidBy", f.getPaidBy())
        .setParameter("season", f.getSeason()).setParameter("expenceSubmitter", f.getExpenceSubmitter()).setParameter("submitDate", f.getSubmitDate())
        .setParameter("approvedDate", f.getApprovedDate()).setParameter("paidDate", f.getPaidDate()).setParameter("externalRef", f.getExternalRef())
        .setParameter("status", f.getStatus()).setParameter("type", f.getType()).setParameter("comment", f.getComment())
        .setParameter("year", f.getYear()).setParameter("id", f.getId());

updateQuery.executeUpdate();
```

However i still consider this as a 'hack' not resolving the real issue.
If someone with jira access to the hibernate project reads this i think it would be appropriate to open a dedicated defect.